# Relate wordpress Ip with domain

Tags: dns, hosting

I have my WordPress hosted in this IP for example: `http://46.102.133.215/project/public_html/`
I'm using linux server.

I bought a domain and it is registered on `NameCheap`. 
Now what should I do, I'm confused. This is my first time, which steps should I do to relate Ip with the domain? 
Please help!

Comment: You'd need to change the DNS records of the domain to point to the new server, and set up the domain on the new server. How that is done depends on the type of server, most hosting companies offer a control panel for it. If you know the OS of the server, you can look up tutorials for how to set up new web sites ("Virtual hosts" in Apache-speak). In its current form, this is definitely too broad for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can go through following steps to map your domain to your web hosting server.

1) Your web host must have provided you with the "New Account 
Information" containing web hosting login information such as, FTP details, Nameservers, etc.

2) Grab the Nameservers and login to Namecheap control panel. Follow below tutorial and change the nameservers to those which are provided by your web host.

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/767/10/how-can-i-change-the-nameservers-for-my-domain

3) Once you change the nameservers, DNS propagation may take few hours and your website will start resolving your web host. You'll be able to browse your website with the domain name itself.

4) To run a WordPress website on temporary URL, earlier you might have done the changes in ***WordPress Address*** and ***Site Address*** variables. You'll  have to correct these changes.

5) Replace these entries with your actual domain name and setup. You can refer following tutorial to change these variables.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress